# Copyright Issue and Substantial Similarity

Tags: copyright

I've been asked to create several images to look like ships from various science fiction series. I've read a bit about copyright laws, and I know there's a thing called substantial similarity, but I'm unclear as to how this works. I'm not actually copying the source work, but I'll be using it as a reference. I've been given free license for style, so if I do them in, say, pixel art, would that constitute enough of a change?

To cite an example: "Game Dev Tycoon" uses obvious representations of the Xbox, Wii, etc., but somehow has *gotten away* with it.

Any help or resources anyone could point out would be appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posting detected: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/copyright-issue-and-substantial-similarity

Comment: Yes, as I said in that other post, I was unsure on which site to post this question, so I asked on both. There's no "Legal Advice" SE site.

Comment: There wont be a legal advise SE site because that is opening a can of worms and could make SE liable plus you should consult a copyright attorney in your area.  In regards to the other post please do not cross post on SE but request the mod of the site to transfer it in a comment or ask in meta if the question is in scope.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question as it stands now as it relates to matters of law, we have no idea of your jurisdiction, and most importantly we are *not* your lawyer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues and better asked of an attorney.